# Getting 403 Forbidden requesting Amazon S3 file

Tags: python

I want to get the size of a file on Amazon S3 without having to download it. My attempt has been to try and send a HTTP HEAD and the request returned will include content-length HTTP header.

Here is my code:

```
import httplib
import urllib
urlPATH = urllib.unquote("/ticket/fakefile.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIX44POYZ6RD4KV2A&Expires=1495332764&Signature=swGAc7vqIkFbtrfXjTPmY3Jffew%3D")

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("cptl.s3.amazonaws.com")
conn.request("HEAD", urlPATH, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
)
res = conn.getresponse()
print res.status, res.reason
```

Error message is:

```
403 Forbidden
```

So to escape the "%" in the URL, I used urllib.unquote and after getting 403 Forbidden, I also attempt to try and add in some headers as I thought Amazon may  be only returning files that appear to be requested by a browser, but I continue to get 403 error.

Is this a case of Amazon needing particular arguments to service the HTTP request properly or is my code bad?

Comment: Are you sure you need the extra quoting? Does it return 403 even without that, too?

Comment: What extra quoting are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant the `urllib.unquote`.

Comment: Ah, it still runs without the unquote but symptoms are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.... I found a solution by using a workaround. My best guess is that curl/wget are missing http headers in the request to S3, so they all fail and browser works. Tried to start analyzing the request but didn't.

Ultimately, got it working with the following code:

```
import urllib
d = urllib.urlopen("S3URL")
print d.info()['Content-Length']
```

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden mildly points to an auth problem.  Are you sure your access key and signature are correct?

If there's doubt, you could always try and get the metadata via [Boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which handles all the auth stuff for you (pulling from config files or data you've passed in).  Heck, if it works, you can even maybe turn on debug mode and see what it's actually sending that works.

Comment: If I copy and paste the URL from my code in to a web browser, it downloads fine.

Comment: Ok, I might have to try that. Thanks

Comment: try the copy-paste thing into a commandline with `curl` - it hides a lot less than a web browser.